# Force a constexpr function to be evaluated at runtime?

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr

Consider the following scenario:

```
template <bool expensive>
constexpr auto computeValue() {
  // ...
}

void funcA() {
  static constexpr auto value_a = computeValue<false>();  // should be at compile time
  // ...
}

void funcB() {
  static const auto value_b = computeValue<true>();  // should be at runtime
  // ...
}
```

In my scenario `computeValue<true>` is an expensive computation and is unable to be evaluated at compile time due to an out of memory error on my system. However, it is able to be run in an acceptable amount of time at runtime, with the same computer. `computeValue<false>` does not have this  problem, which is why it is computed at compile time in `funcA`.

The problem is that the compiler still tries to evalute `computeValue<true>()` at compile time despite the fact that I left out the `constexpr`, and subsequently runs out of memory. Is there a way to force it to leave this computation for runtime evaluation?

Comment: Maybe completely irrelevant, but can't you evaluate the expression at run-time once and hard-code the value in the source ?

Comment: You can add an argument and if the argument is not a constant expression then the function evaluates at runtime.

Comment: Why use the same function then? Simply have `compile_time_value()` and `run_time_value()` functions. You could probably get what you want with template specialization but unless you really need `computevalue` to be a template with a `bool` parameter, it would only make code more complex without benefits.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The output of `computeValue` is a large `std::array<uint8_t, n>`, so I'm writing it to a header file and `#include`ing it in the source code. I but I still need code for running it that one time and writing it to a file.

Comment: Create a new empty file, get the file size and add it (0) to each value within your function. Of course the optimizer will statically determine that the file belongs only to your process and evaluate it at compile-time to a no-op ;-) The optimizer determines that the world is deterministic and denies to do any runtime work at all from now on ...

Answer (score 1):

You can’t force the compiler to do anything—it can constant-fold anything and everything, because only the behavior of the program matters (and “exceeding implementation limits” is a valid reason to reject a program).  However, you can discourage it with minimal redundancy by **wrapping** the constexpr function in a non-constexpr function:

```
template<bool E>
auto runtimeValue() {return computeValue<E>();}

void funcB() {
  static const auto value_b = runtimeValue<true>();
  // ...
}
```

If that isn’t enough, you could introduce a **parameter** to inject a false runtime dependency (that the compiler might or might not see through).  At the cost of losing the deduced return type, you can define `runtimeValue` in a different **translation unit**.

Comment: Is it really valid to choose to constant-fold and reject the program due to an implementation-defined limit on some aspect of constexpr calculation (ops, iterations, function calls, ...)? The result isn't "as if" it didn't.

Comment: @JeffGarrett Probably it was not on purpose by the compiler to get an OOM error.

Comment: Nevermind. The language on implementation limits is very broad.

Answer (score 1):

First I came here looking for an answer, but didn't find any.
In the end I came up with this :

```
template <typename fn_t, typename... args_t>
auto force_runtime_call(fn_t fn, args_t&&... args)
{
    return fn(std::forward<args_t>(args)...);
}
```

And then

```
void funcB() 
{
  static const auto value_b = force_runtime_call(computeValue<true>);
}
```

The template accepts a callable and will invoke it and for that it needs it to be available at runtime.

Comment: I don't think the "accepts a callable" has anything to do with it: `force_runtime_call` is simply not declared `constexpr` (like `runtimeValue`).

Comment: Ofcourse constexpr is not declared to be constexpr, that is what tries to move code to be executed at runtime. Though in some cases even the optimizer may "see through" this and still generate inline code only.

Answer (score 0):

`const int` might be "promoted" to `constexpr int` if initializer is `constexpr`.

Dropping `const` would make disallow the `constexpr` (compiler might still decide to optimize and does some computation at compile time, but result would be unusable in constant expression):

```
void funcB()
{
  static auto init_value_b = computeValue<true>();
  static const auto value_b = init_value_b; // That const cannot be constexpr
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The only solution I could figure out was to make a second copy of the function except without the `constexpr`.

```
template <bool expensive>
constexpr auto computeValue() {
  // ...
}

template <bool expensive>
auto computeValueRuntime() {
  return computeValue<expensive>();
}

void funcB() {
  static const auto value_b = computeValueRuntime<true>();  // should be (and is) at runtime
  // ...
}
```

This seems pretty inelegant though, so I'm wondering if there's some syntactic way of doing it.

Comment: No. It doesn't mean `computeValue` is being run at runtime, even if `computeValueRuntime` is. This is misleading at best.

Comment: Here's the proof: https://godbolt.org/z/z6hqaaTEb The `computeValueRuntime` function is indeed runtime, but the `computeValue` is ran at compile time and the output is embedded inside the `computeValueRuntime` function.

Comment: Although, simply disabling optimizations will prevent the function to be ran at compile time (in some particular cases)

Comment: I ran the original code locally with a debugger and it does step into `computeValue<true>` at runtime, but only the first time that `funcB` is called (which is exactly what you would expect since `value_b` is `static`. In your example, I can prevent the code from being computed at compile time by simply increasing the loop iterations: https://godbolt.org/z/f5dK8T6nY. But I agree with your sentiment that this doesn't seem like a reliable way to ensure that the work is done at runtime since the compiler still has the option to compute it at compile time.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Yes, compilers have a bias to runtime when disabling optimization. I would say this is convincing enough if you provide evidence (godbolt links) and state that the results may vary. I will remove my downvote given that.